# What is the difference between a median and a population/sample median?

Tags: median

If I have an order statistic, I can rank them from smallest to largest like

$$X_{(1)}, X_{(2)},...,X_{(n)}$$

and there will be some median $X_{m}$.

But I can also have some distribution $f(x)$ and define an integral

$$\int_{0}^m f(x)dx = \frac{1}{2}$$ and, if I solve for $m$, this will be the median for the distribution.

**My Question**

What is the difference between these two types of medians?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your order statistic $X_m$ is the median of your data.  This is your *sample median* and can change depending on what sample you pull.  For example, if you gather a sample of 50 observations on one day and a sample of 50 observations on the next day, it is very likely that $X_m$ calculated from sample 1 will be different from $X_m$ calculated from sample 2.

Using your integral above to solve for $m$ will find you the *population median* - perhaps denoted $M$.  This will not change regardless of what data you pull or the size of your sample.  $M$ is a parameter, not a statistic.

You may use $X_m$ to estimate $M$.  If you were interested in finding the median height of American adults, you may gather a sample of $n$ people and calculate $X_m$.  Of course it will be logistically impossible to measure the height of every adult and calculate $M$ directly, so you use $X_m$ to estimate $M$.

Comment: I thought a population statistic was like the maximum possible number of data points for sample statistic and that then, once you had all the data, it becomes a population statistic and I can find a population median. Is that wrong? if not, how is this kind of population statistic different from simply finding the median of a distribution?

Comment: A statistic is a function of data.  Generally data comes in the form of a sample and thus most often a statistic is based off of a sample, not a population.  Thus, $X_m$ will be a sample statistic.  If there is some case where you are able to gather all of your data, then $X_m$ will still be a statistic but will be based on the entire population and will equal your true median $M$.

Since $f(x)$ is your probability density function, $f(x)$ defines your population and thus finding the median $M$ by integrating $f(x)$ from 0 to $M$ will get you the population median.

Comment: In most cases, however, it is not possible to gather 100% of the population's data so we use sample statistics to estimate population parameters.  If you can gather 100% of the population's data, then there is no need to conduct any statistical inference because you already know the true population values (parameters).  In this case, you can *technically* have population statistics but I think this term is more confusing than using statistic to refer to functions of data from a sample and parameters to refer to true population values.

Comment: Similar logic for sample mode vs population mode I assume then.

Comment: That is correct.